# Chromium build failed

Tags: chromium, ninja

I'm trying to build Chromium 40.0.2214.111

```
ninja -C out/Release chrome
```

But it failed with the error:

```
FAILED: ninja -t msvc -e environment.x86 -- "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\amd64_x86\cl.exe" /nologo /showIncludes /FC @obj\device
bluetooth\device_bluetooth.bluetooth_low_energy_defs_win.obj.rsp /c ..\..\device\bluetooth\bluetooth_low_energy_defs_win.cc /Foobj\device\bluetooth\device_blue
ooth.bluetooth_low_energy_defs_win.obj /Fdobj\device\bluetooth\device_bluetooth.cc.pdb
c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\bluetoothleapis.h(685) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'PFNBLUETOOTH_GATT_EVENT_CALLBACK'
c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\bluetoothleapis.h(711) : error C2065: 'BLUETOOTH_GATT_EVENT_HANDLE' : undeclared identifier
c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\bluetoothleapis.h(711) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'EventHandle'
c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\bluetoothleapis.h(711) : warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\bluetoothleapis.h(713) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
[8/6758] ACTION Generating C++ API bundle code for function registration
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I have tried to solve the issue with the google, but I did not succeed